# define a delegate that not get dereferenced?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase-cloud-messaging, appdelegate

Right now I am implementing FIRMessaging for receiving notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging. I made a test by creating a new project into firebase console, then registered my bundle ID, I download config file and copied to my project (Single view App), then I installed necessary pods. In my AppDelegate I use FIRMessaging for getting notifications and Firebase core for connecting to firebase.

I could make this work. I use `<FIRMessagingDelegate>` protocol in my AppDelegate and implement the methods that it defines:

1.- `messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:` which receives a token when the app starts.

2.- `messaging:didReceiveMessage:` that receives notifications from firebase.

I wrote next code in my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
[FIRApp configure];
firebaseDelegate * delegateObject = [[firebaseDelegate alloc] init];
FIRMessaging * message = [FIRMessaging messaging];
message.shouldEstablishDirectChannel = YES;
message.autoInitEnabled = YES;
message.delegate = self;
NSLog(@"TOKEN : %@",message.FCMToken);

NSLog(@"Firebase initialization completed");
return YES;
```

}

Here is my firebaseDelegate.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <FirebaseMessaging/FIRMessaging.h>
@interface firebaseDelegate : NSObject <FIRMessagingDelegate> 
@end
```

Here my implementation

```
#import "firebaseDelegate.h"
@implementation firebaseDelegate 

- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveRegistrationToken:(NSString *)fcmToken
{
    NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:fcmToken forKey:@"token"];
}

-(void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage
{
    NSLog(@"Message: %@",[remoteMessage appData]);
}
@end
```

And here is the implementation of the second method I previously mentioned (that is inside my AppDelegate):

```
-(void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage{
NSLog(@"Message: %@",[remoteMessage appData]);}
```

And when I fire a notification, I received it and appear on the log like this
[image]

But when I try to define a class that conforms this two methods and change the delegate (the line `message.delegate = self;`) for an instance of this class like this:

```
message.delegate = delegateObject;
```

I get this in the log:
[image]

It appears that the reference for that object get destroyed, and when using AppDelegate (self) it work fine, I did some reasearching and found that AppDelegate is always present.

How could I create a class that can works as a delegate and it does not get dereferenced ?

Comment: is delegateObject class a `NSObject`? It must be. You can share your `delegateObject` class code.

Comment: Sorry, I just added my firebaseDelegate class @elia

Comment: is it just FIRMessagingDelegate or any other delegate is must be implemented to it?

Comment: And can you try adding your delegate object to your AppDelegate.h file and init it.

Comment: @elia, your were right, I added to AppDelegate (), which I think is an extension for AppDelegate. Also I added an init method and initialized the ivar and it worked, thank you.

Comment: I will add as answer, you can accept it as correct answer, I am glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your delegate into `AppDelegate` like below.

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{

firebaseDelegate * delegateObject;

}
@end
```

Then it must be worked.